# Ansible. Create different ec2 instance error: Minimum instance count must be greater than zero

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I try to create few ec2 instance which are have different count and tag. 3 Webserver instance deploying. but one load balancer gives an error message:

```
`TASK [createIns_ec2 : Provision instance(s)] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': {u'count': 3}, 'key': u'webserver'})
failed: [localhost] (item={'value': {u'count': 1}, 'key': u'lb'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"key": "lb", "value": {"count": 1}}, "msg": "Instance creation failed => InvalidParameterValue: Minimum instance count must be greater than zero"}
`
```

how i can create different instance without duplicate ec2 code block, or how to fix this issue?

part of playbook

```
- name: add ec2 variables
  include_vars:
    file: ../../../group_vars/main.yml
- name: Provision instance(s)
  ec2:
    aws_access_key: "{{ec2_access_key}}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ec2_secret_key}}"
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    id: "{{ id }}"
    group_id: "{{ result_sec_group.group_id }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    instance_type: t2.micro
    region: "{{ region }}"
    wait: true
    instance_tags:
      Name: "{{ item.key }}"
    count: "{{ item.value.count }}"
  with_dict: "{{ EC2_VMS }}"`
```

part of vars file

```
region: eu-central-1
image: ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5
EC2_VMS:
  lb:
    count: 1
  webserver:
    count: 3
`
```

debug log of this task

```
    TASK [createIns_ec2 : Provision instance(s)] *******************************************************************************************
task path: /home/arudy/playbooks/site/roles/createIns_ec2/tasks/main.yml:36
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/arudy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-21511yOIVIE/tmpUGZTpJ TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447/AnsiballZ_ec2.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447/AnsiballZ_ec2.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447/AnsiballZ_ec2.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982751.31-38290473535447/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
changed: [localhost] => (item={'value': {u'count': 3}, 'key': u'webserver'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": true, 
    "instance_ids": [
        "i-04b65126b96685ef1", 
        "i-0b8e340b0b6dfd5d5", 
        "i-0ee402b469386661c"
    ], 
    "instances": [
        {
            "ami_launch_index": "0", 
            "architecture": "x86_64", 
            "block_device_mapping": {
                "/dev/sda1": {
                    "delete_on_termination": true, 
                    "status": "attached", 
                    "volume_id": "vol-07a85b75477bea7cb"
                }
            }, 
            "dns_name": "ec2-3-120-159-13.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "ebs_optimized": false, 
            "groups": {
                "sg-0a53dff937dec9e1e": "AWS_EC2_tst-sec"
            }, 
            "hypervisor": "xen", 
            "id": "i-04b65126b96685ef1", 
            "image_id": "ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5", 
            "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
            "kernel": null, 
            "key_name": "my_aws", 
            "launch_time": "2019-12-10T12:59:12.000Z", 
            "placement": "eu-central-1b", 
            "private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-32-38.eu-central-1.compute.internal", 
            "private_ip": "172.31.32.38", 
            "public_dns_name": "ec2-3-120-159-13.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "public_ip": "3.120.159.13", 
            "ramdisk": null, 
            "region": "eu-central-1", 
            "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
            "root_device_type": "ebs", 
            "state": "running", 
            "state_code": 16, 
            "tags": {
                "Name": "webserver"
            }, 
            "tenancy": "default", 
            "virtualization_type": "hvm"
        }, 
        {
            "ami_launch_index": "2", 
            "architecture": "x86_64", 
            "block_device_mapping": {
                "/dev/sda1": {
                    "delete_on_termination": true, 
                    "status": "attached", 
                    "volume_id": "vol-0f1471bd806709653"
                }
            }, 
            "dns_name": "ec2-3-120-205-176.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "ebs_optimized": false, 
            "groups": {
                "sg-0a53dff937dec9e1e": "AWS_EC2_tst-sec"
            }, 
            "hypervisor": "xen", 
            "id": "i-0b8e340b0b6dfd5d5", 
            "image_id": "ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5", 
            "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
            "kernel": null, 
            "key_name": "my_aws", 
            "launch_time": "2019-12-10T12:59:12.000Z", 
            "placement": "eu-central-1b", 
            "private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-36-29.eu-central-1.compute.internal", 
            "private_ip": "172.31.36.29", 
            "public_dns_name": "ec2-3-120-205-176.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "public_ip": "3.120.205.176", 
            "ramdisk": null, 
            "region": "eu-central-1", 
            "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
            "root_device_type": "ebs", 
            "state": "running", 
            "state_code": 16, 
            "tags": {
                "Name": "webserver"
            }, 
            "tenancy": "default", 
            "virtualization_type": "hvm"
        }, 
        {
            "ami_launch_index": "1", 
            "architecture": "x86_64", 
            "block_device_mapping": {
                "/dev/sda1": {
                    "delete_on_termination": true, 
                    "status": "attached", 
                    "volume_id": "vol-074dc3eb3dfa5cb91"
                }
            }, 
            "dns_name": "ec2-3-124-186-0.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "ebs_optimized": false, 
            "groups": {
                "sg-0a53dff937dec9e1e": "AWS_EC2_tst-sec"
            }, 
            "hypervisor": "xen", 
            "id": "i-0ee402b469386661c", 
            "image_id": "ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5", 
            "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
            "kernel": null, 
            "key_name": "my_aws", 
            "launch_time": "2019-12-10T12:59:12.000Z", 
            "placement": "eu-central-1b", 
            "private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-47-172.eu-central-1.compute.internal", 
            "private_ip": "172.31.47.172", 
            "public_dns_name": "ec2-3-124-186-0.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "public_ip": "3.124.186.0", 
            "ramdisk": null, 
            "region": "eu-central-1", 
            "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
            "root_device_type": "ebs", 
            "state": "running", 
            "state_code": 16, 
            "tags": {
                "Name": "webserver"
            }, 
            "tenancy": "default", 
            "virtualization_type": "hvm"
        }
    ], 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "assign_public_ip": null, 
            "aws_access_key": "key", 
            "aws_secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "count": 3, 
            "count_tag": null, 
            "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false, 
            "ebs_optimized": false, 
            "ec2_url": null, 
            "exact_count": null, 
            "group": null, 
            "group_id": [
                "sg-0a53dff937dec9e1e"
            ], 
            "id": "AWS_EC2_tst", 
            "image": "ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5", 
            "instance_ids": null, 
            "instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior": "stop", 
            "instance_profile_name": null, 
            "instance_tags": {
                "Name": "webserver"
            }, 
            "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
            "kernel": null, 
            "key_name": "my_aws", 
            "monitoring": false, 
            "network_interfaces": null, 
            "placement_group": null, 
            "private_ip": null, 
            "profile": null, 
            "ramdisk": null, 
            "region": "eu-central-1", 
            "security_token": null, 
            "source_dest_check": null, 
            "spot_launch_group": null, 
            "spot_price": null, 
            "spot_type": "one-time", 
            "spot_wait_timeout": 600, 
            "state": "present", 
            "tenancy": "default", 
            "termination_protection": null, 
            "user_data": null, 
            "validate_certs": true, 
            "volumes": null, 
            "vpc_subnet_id": null, 
            "wait": true, 
            "wait_timeout": 300, 
            "zone": null
        }
    }, 
    "item": {
        "key": "webserver", 
        "value": {
            "count": 3
        }
    }, 
    "tagged_instances": []
}
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/arudy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-21511yOIVIE/tmpwFtFnB TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854/AnsiballZ_ec2.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854/AnsiballZ_ec2.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854/AnsiballZ_ec2.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1575982784.79-142659143526854/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_payload_mcI5bP/ansible_ec2_payload.zip/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2.py", line 1158, in create_instances
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 977, in run_instances
    verb='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1208, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)

failed: [localhost] (item={'value': {u'count': 1}, 'key': u'lb'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "assign_public_ip": null, 
            "aws_access_key": "KEY", 
            "aws_secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "count": 1, 
            "count_tag": null, 
            "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false, 
            "ebs_optimized": false, 
            "ec2_url": null, 
            "exact_count": null, 
            "group": null, 
            "group_id": [
                "sg-0a53dff937dec9e1e"
            ], 
            "id": "AWS_EC2_tst", 
            "image": "ami-0cc0a36f626a4fdf5", 
            "instance_ids": null, 
            "instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior": "stop", 
            "instance_profile_name": null, 
            "instance_tags": {
                "Name": "lb"
            }, 
            "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
            "kernel": null, 
            "key_name": "my_aws", 
            "monitoring": false, 
            "network_interfaces": null, 
            "placement_group": null, 
            "private_ip": null, 
            "profile": null, 
            "ramdisk": null, 
            "region": "eu-central-1", 
            "security_token": null, 
            "source_dest_check": null, 
            "spot_launch_group": null, 
            "spot_price": null, 
            "spot_type": "one-time", 
            "spot_wait_timeout": 600, 
            "state": "present", 
            "tenancy": "default", 
            "termination_protection": null, 
            "user_data": null, 
            "validate_certs": true, 
            "volumes": null, 
            "vpc_subnet_id": null, 
            "wait": true, 
            "wait_timeout": 300, 
            "zone": null
        }
    }, 
    "item": {
        "key": "lb", 
        "value": {
            "count": 1
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Instance creation failed => InvalidParameterValue: Minimum instance count must be greater than zero"
}
```

Comment: Just add "count: 1" under ec2 module parameters. I think issue is not not with load balancer but ec2 creation.

Comment: I think the same. I have 'count: "{{ item.value.count }}"', this value should be take from vars file.

Comment: Can you try running your playbook in debug mode.  ("-vvv"  option  at the end of your playbook command). And paste output here.

Comment: Yes, i can. Because of log size, I add his to message in header

Comment: I really cant see any issues technically. Following points ( try) can help in debugging.  1. Try to run lb and webserver on at time 2. Increase count to 2 and try if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand point number one.
I try with 2 loadbalancer instance, and get the same error, lb count=3 dont gives error, and end with status "ok", but instances was not created.
i think this construction is not allowed for use